# “Smallest” non-zero linear combination of vectors to obtain a non-negative vector

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices

We say that a vector $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^j$ is non-negative if it is of the form
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    x_j \\
\end{bmatrix}

where $x_{j} \geq 0$.

Suppose that $A$ is a $j \times j$ integer valued matrix with entries in the interval $[-n,n]$. What is the smallest possible value of $\delta_{j} \geq 0$ so that if $\varepsilon > 0$ then there exists an integer valued vector $\mathbf{x}_{A} \neq \mathbf{0}$ such that $A\cdot\mathbf{x}_{A}$ is non-negative, and $|\mathbf{x}_{A}| \leq C_{\epsilon}n^{\delta_{j} + \varepsilon}$ (here $C_{\epsilon}$ is a positive constant dependent only on $\varepsilon$)?

Note that we can find candidate values $\delta_{j} < \infty$, but I have not proved that here. I mainly seek a “non-trivial” upper bound for $\delta_{j}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a rigorous argument but just a thought.

Let $y:=Ax_A$ be a non-negative integer vector, then $x_A = A^{-1}y$ and thus
$$|\lambda_1|\leq |\lambda_1||y| \leq |x_A|\leq |\lambda_j||y|,$$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_j$ are the smallest and the largest (by absolute value) eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$, which are reciprocals of the largest and smallest eigenvalues of $A$.

Also, we may note that for some $i$ there exists a nonzero integer vector $z:=\mathrm{det}(A)A^{-1}e_i$ such that $Az$ is non-negative. It follows that
$$|x_A| \leq |z| \leq \mathrm{det}(A) |\lambda_j|.$$

I did not check carefully, but it seems that for $A$ with entries in $[-n,n]$, these bounds may be exponential be in $n$.